# Android Studio is giving me AAPT error on uneditable XML files

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to set up OpenCV in android studio but whenever I try to build my project I get this error

```
/home/oliver/AndroidStudioProjects/Opencvreal/app/build/intermediates
/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:33: AAPT: error: 
resource style/AppTheme (aka com.example.opencvreal:style/AppTheme) not found.
```

The error is with the generated XML file which from my understanding is uneditable. Here is the main and generated XML files

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="opencv.codeonion.com.opencv_test">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity_show_camera"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <supports-screens   android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus" android:required="false"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: just create a style with AppTheme in style.xml  for example -:     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">  </style>

Answer (score 2):

In your **app > main > res > values > styles.xml** make sure style name="AppTheme" is there. If already there then clean and rebuild your project hopefully this will work.

```
   <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```